# Set a style to selection range in webpage

Tags: html, css, selection, stylesheet

When I set some styles(like Line-height) to a block tag(P,Dive,...) there is no problem.
But when I selected a text that starts from middle of one block and ends in another block (= includes some Paragraphs) I can't recognize the tags in selection range. 
How i can do this,pleas?

Comment: can you include some code and explain the problem you are having. the question doesn't make sense without an example/code

Comment: please add code or demo link

Comment: I had explained it in there: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9ecd8cb4-b3c5-4df0-bd5e-8765ec011a4a/how-can-i-apply-a-lineheight-to-text-in-a-webbrowser-document?forum=winforms